# How to understand the path integral of $U(1)$ gauge field under Coulomb gauge?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, wick-rotation

I want to obtain Green's function of $U(1)$ gauge field under Coulomb gauge. For some reason, I want to finish it in Euclidean space, i.e. both time-space $x_\mu$ and field strength $A_\mu$, so that we do not need to distinguish upper and lower indices. The action is:
$$S\left[A_{\mu}\right]=\int d \tau d x\left(\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(\nabla \cdot \textbf{A}\right)^{2}\right)$$ the last term $\frac{1}{\alpha}(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A})^{2}$ is Coulomb gauge from Faddeev-Popov technique. Since there is no dynamic term for $A_0$, I can integral out $A_0$ and obtain:
$$S[A]=\sum_{q}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{q^{2}} \omega_{n}^{2}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{q} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{-q}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{q} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{q}\right)+\sum_{q}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\boldsymbol{q} \times A_{q}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{q} \times \boldsymbol{A}_{-q}\right)+\omega_{n}^{2} \boldsymbol{A}_{q} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{-q}\right)\right)$$
where $\omega_{n}$ is imaginary-frequency since all of the operation are in Euclidean space. And we can always divide $\boldsymbol{A}_{q}$ as two part, i.e. longitudinal component and transverse component:
$$\boldsymbol{A}_{q}=\boldsymbol{A}_{q}-\frac{\boldsymbol{q}\left(\boldsymbol{q} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{q}\right)}{\boldsymbol{q}^{2}}+\frac{\boldsymbol{q}\left(\boldsymbol{q} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{q}\right)}{\boldsymbol{q}^{2}}=\boldsymbol{A}_{q}^{\perp}+\boldsymbol{A}_{q}^{\parallel}$$
where
$$\begin{aligned} \boldsymbol{A}_{\boldsymbol{q}}^{\perp} &=\boldsymbol{A}_{q}-\frac{\boldsymbol{q}\left(\boldsymbol{q} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{q}\right)}{\boldsymbol{q}^{2}} \\ \boldsymbol{A}_{\boldsymbol{q}}^{\|} &=\frac{\boldsymbol{q}\left(\boldsymbol{q} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{q}\right)}{\boldsymbol{q}^{2}} \end{aligned}$$
As the result, the final action is:
$$S[\boldsymbol{A}]=\sum_{ q}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha} \boldsymbol{q}^{2}\right) \boldsymbol{A}_{q}^{\|} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{-q}^{\|}+\sum_{q} \frac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{q}^{2}+\omega_{n}^{2}\right) \boldsymbol{A}_{q}^{\perp} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{-q}^{\perp}$$
I can under stand the transverse part, i.e. two mode with Green function:
$$G^{\perp}(k,\omega)=\frac{1}{\boldsymbol{q}^{2}+\omega_{n}^{2}}$$
with pole at $E_q=|q|$, which can be considered as two polarization mode of photon.

However, although I know longitudinal part is not the real mode, **how can I understand it directly from expression**?

Furthermore, if this $U(1)$ gauge field couples with Goldstone mode $\theta$ which after spontaneous symmetry breaking, e.g.
$$S\left[\theta, A_{\mu}\right]=\int d \tau d^{d} x \rho_{0}\left(D_{\mu} \theta\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{\alpha}(\nabla \cdot A)^{2}$$
then integral out $\theta$ field and $A_0$ field will gives:
$$S[\boldsymbol{A}]=\sum_{ q}\left(X(\omega_n,q)+\frac{1}{\alpha} \boldsymbol{q}^{2}\right) \boldsymbol{A}_{q}^{\|} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{-q}^{\|}+\sum_{q} \frac{1}{2} Y(\omega_n,q) \boldsymbol{A}_{q}^{\perp} \cdot \boldsymbol{A}_{-q}^{\perp}$$
and Green function for $\boldsymbol{A}_{q}^{\|}$ can be considered as $\left(X(\omega_n,\boldsymbol{q})+\frac{1}{\alpha} \boldsymbol{q}^{2}\right)^{-1}$, but different value for $\alpha$ will change the pole of Green function, which is different from traditional conclusion: pole of $\widetilde{D}_{F}^{\mu \nu}(k)=\frac{-i}{k^{2}+i \epsilon}\left(g^{\mu \nu}-(1-\alpha) \frac{k^{\mu} k^{\nu}}{k^{2}}\right)$ does not depend on value $\alpha$. Thus, **I'm confused that did I make any mistakes in the above process?**